# What exactly is the ability of Ultimate Farm Tools?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

While using the Ultimate Watering can i noticed that not only did it empty right away but all my crops had been watere

At first i though it was like the Mystic Watering Can from Harvest Moon DS which waters the entire screen however when i went to use it, it showed the range which was all around me and crops outside of this range was watered too.

So what exactly is the ability of Ultimate Farm Tools like the Hoe, Watering Can and Scythe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply increases the affected range, like in most of the games. I actually end up putting most of my fields in the tiered field with the spring. It makes watering easier. You simply use the spring to water in the morning and use the watering can in the evening. If you stand in the right spot  you can water the whole screen in 2 or 3 uses. But for more information please check this guide: http://fogu.com/hm11/index.php
It's the best for Harvest Moon help.